# Solve $\sin(x) = \cos(x)$ where $0°\leq x\leq 450°$

Tags: trigonometry

How many solutions are there: $\sin(x) = \cos(x)$ where $0°\leq x\leq 450°$?

My solution: transform the equation to $\tan(x)=1$ , using the unit circle I see 3 solutions:

$x_1 = π/4$ , $x_2 = 5π/4$, $x_3 = 9π/4$.

The maths book says there are 7 solutions, where is my mistake?

Comment: I also see only three solutions ... https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pkr7sw71hw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, there are only $3$ solutions to the equation $\sin(x)=\cos(x)$ in the interval $[0,\frac{5}{2}\pi]$. Perhaps you might've missed something else in the question? A graphical approach shows that there are $3$ solutions at $\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{7\pi}{4}$ and $\frac{9\pi}{4}$.

[image]